# How to mandate a constant in Java

Tags: java, interface, constants

I'm using JAX-RS to create REST Web Services.

I need to make the value of the `@Path` annotation on my `Resource` Classes publicly accessible. Using reflection to obtain this value seems a little heavy.

I thought I would hold the value in a `public static final String`, so that it is both accessible to the `@Path` annotation and to other Classes.

What is the best way to mandate that a Class provide this constant? I was under the impression that using constants in an Interface was an anti-pattern (Effective Java 2nd Edition).

**EDIT:**

As pointed out Effective Java says "If the constants are strongly tied to an existing class or interface, you should add them to the class or interface".

In my situation, the `@Path` will be the same for all implementers of the Interface, and the Interface will provide methods, so I think I am safe to add the constant to the Interface.

Comment: Add a getter method to a private field?

Comment: effective java doesn't say using constants in an interface is an anti-pattern. It says using an interface solely for constants is an anti-pattern, "constant interface" is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already have [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), I'll quote it for you (p. 98-99):

> If you want to export contants, there are several reasonable choices.
>   If the constants are strongly tied to an existing class or interface,
>   you should add them to the class or interface. For example, all of the
>   boxed numerical primitive classes, such as Integer and Double, export
>   MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE constants. If the constants are best viewed as
>   members of an enumerated type, you should export them with an enum
>   type. Otherwise, you should export the constants with a
>   noninstantiable utility class.

---

However, the answer above deals with exporting constants. If you want to "mandate that a Class provide this constant", that's a different thing, and having constants in your interface does not do that. Only way you could mandate such a thing is to have a getter for it in your interface.

Comment: +1 especially for **Otherwise, you should export the constants with a noninstantiable utility class.**

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that if I were to have a getter in my Interface, that I could not access it in my @Path annotation?

Comment: @retrodev don't have experience about that, but my guess is that you should be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

If that is an option you could simply add the functionality as a simple method. `static` has certain issues with inheritance and is not always a great idea.

```
interface HasPath {
    String getPath();
}

class Foo implements HasPath {
    private static final String PATH = "/my/path";

    @Override
    public void String getPath() {
        return PATH;
    }

    @Annotated(PATH) void foo() { }
}
```